# Why is SQL Server constantly trying to use my LocalDb database and blocking Entity Framework from using it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I've been having this problem on and off for months with this particular project.

I've got my database running on LocalDb which seemed the simplest option for the client's requirements. He wanted as little involvement in setting up the software as possible so I figured going with even SQLEXRESS would be too much...

Anyway, the database file is located on the client's hard drive - lets say at
`C:\Client Name\App Name\data\Database.mdf`

This path is identical on dev, testing, production systems. Before I debug I ensure the database exists by running `update-database` in PM Console.

Sometimes when I try to debug, I get the following error:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in EntityFramework.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot create file 'C:\Client Name\App Name\data\Database.mdf' because it already exists. Change the file path or the file name, and retry the operation.

I learned yesterday that this could happen if the file is in use and a bit of dumb luck showed me that in this case, if I try to copy the file to a new location, Windows will tell me what's using it.

Almost every time I've done this, Windows has reported that SQL Server is using the file. I actually have to kill sqlservr.exe to allow the copy which lets me know that the file can now be used again.

Thing is... This particular database file isn't attached in Management Studio so shouldn't be in use by SQL Server at all as far as I know. I did attach it once so that I could copy data from the older version (there isn't much continuity happening here if I find I have to delete the database and start again).

So why is SQL Server using the database when the database isn't even attached to the SQL Server instance?

Comment: Have a look to your services, and find SQL server services, one of them is for sure.

Comment: @MRsa I'm sorry, I don't understand... One of them is what for sure?

Comment: Not being attached isn't the same as not having an open file handle, although SQL Server *should* close all handles to the database files when it's detached. Try `sp_readerrorlog` on the instance to see if it has anything useful to say about when it's attaching/detaching the database. (Note, also, that you should preferably use the `sqllocaldb` tool to cleanly stop LocalDB instances, otherwise the server has to run recovery when it next starts.)

Comment: LocalDB is a lightweight version of the SQL Server Express Database Engine which is installed with VS. When you are copying database, VS still run service. By default service should stop after you close VS. If service is not stoped or VS is open, db file shoud be locked.